# Start django server from another package

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a package in python that has command line and gui components, the gui is built with a django web app

so the package structure would be like this:

/my_packagel
..../gui
........manage.py
......../django_project_name
......../app

then I would call my package from another directory like so
/other_directory
.....my_package_manage.py
...../projects_folder

When I call my_package_manage.py I can successfully call my_package scripts that is properly installed in the python path. But when I try to start the django server, it tells me that 'app' module is not found,

How can I start the django runserver by calling it from a parent package?
How can I make the django app find the 'projects_folder' which is in the pachage caller script (my_project_manage.py)

Comment: what is my_package_manage.py? do you mean my_package/gui/manage.py or a different manage.py file?

Comment: You better show your `settings.py` file. Django uses the `settings.py` file, which has the `INSTALLED_APPS` constant, which should contain your `app`, *but in such a way that it is on the `PYTHONPATH`*. Thus, it probably should be something like `my_package.gui.app` in INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Evert gave the correct answer! The settings.py was not configured correctly, thanks!!